# Laravel validation unique with where closure

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I have a table called `taxonomy`. It's columns are `id`, `name`, `slug`, `type` (tag, category). I have created a separate controller for tag and category.

Now I need to apply a unique validation rule on slug:

```
where type = tag
```

Comment: did you solved this question ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Unique](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#rule-unique) rule with the additional where clause

```
'slug' => Rule::unique('taxonomy')->where(function ($query) {
     return $query->where('type', 'tag');
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can apply `unique` rule like this for `insert` and `update` both in single validation function.

```
public function validateTaxonomy(Request $request){
    if(isset($request->id) && $request->id){
        $id = ','.$request->id.',id,type,'.$request->tag;
    }else{
        $id = ',Null,id,type,'.$request->tag;
    }
    $rules = [
            'slug' => 'required|unique:taxonomy,slug'.$id,
    ];
    return Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
}
```

Example to call from `store` function

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $validator = $this->validateTaxonomy($request);
    if($validator->fails()){
        return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
    }
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
    'postData' => 'unique:table_name,column_name'

see more validation here: 
[Validation Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation)

Answer (score 0):

[Unique](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-unique) rule with the additional where clause

```
'slug' => Rule::unique('taxonomy')->where('type', 'tag')
```